# Using SQL Server Session State With Azure SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, session

I'm trying to set up my ASP.NET application to use SQL Server mode for `SessionState`. However, I've run into an issue. I'm using Azure SQL for data storage.

Normally you would run `aspnet_regsql.exe` to set up the database that contains all the necessary tables for managing session state but apparently the SQL statements that are executed do not work with Azure SQL.

So I learned about ASP.NET universal providers and tried to follow the following tutorial:

https://www.sanganakauthority.com/2014/08/session-management-using-sql-azure-and.html

However, I don't know how I'm supposed to set up the database with the necessary tables?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That article says the tables are created automatically. Is that not what you experience?

Comment: I am trying to get this to work too and the table is not being created for me.